# Execute Jenkinsfile from filesystem

Tags: jenkins

*disclaimer: I'm new to Jenkins.*

I am working on a Jenkins that must be runnable locally. The goal is to be able to edit our jobs and test them locally before pushing our changes to the 'real' Jenkins.

We work with `Jenkinsfile` and job-DSL (don't know if this matters).

I would like to be able to edit my `Jenkinsfile` locally, then go to my localhost:8080 and tell Jenkins to *execute* this `Jenkinsfile` to update our jobs.

First, I would force Jenkins to read the new `Jenkinsfile`. I think this is doable with a kind of a job (I suppose).

Then, I would like to also run a watcher on job files (`.groovy`, `.dsl` and `Jenkinsfile`) to trigger the update.

I know how to retrieve `Jenkinsfile` from SCM so that Jenkins can take care of everything but I don't know how to execute a `Jenkinsfile` that already is on the same filesystem than Jenkins, inside the `jenkins_home` (I can put it anywhere although).

I'm pretty sure this question is kind of stupid but I can't achieve this.

#### note:

I know that `Jenkinsfile` seems to be used only while using SCM, as the documentation says so. But when you create a pipeline using the UI, you are writing a `Jenkinsfile` (right?) so it should be possible to trigger the same functions used when Jenkins interpret your pipeline created through the UI.

Comment: The UI does not create a Jenkinsfile for you. Usually you setup your pipeline by creating one in the UI. In most cases the pipeline will be bound to a specific SCM (or even branch). This is where you can test your different versions of the Jenkinsfile (dev-branch for example). Jenkins will always use the Jenkinsfile from your branch so you can change it as often as you want. I don't think you can do this without a SCM.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was afraid of that answer. So if you want to be able to run a Jenkins locally, you **have to** do some changes to your job, push your changes to your SCM and then retrieve those changes through Jenkins? BTW I lack of vocabulary. I was thinking that pipelines were created via `Jenkinsfile`s (so the whole script that start with `pipeline {` was a `Jenkinsfile`).

Comment: Yes (at least I don't know a different way to execute a Jenkinsfile). This is what Jenkins was built for. You want to execute specific actions (the ones in the Jenkinsfile) after someone pushes changes into your SCM. You could try to search for something like 'Jenkins with local git branch' but I can't tell you if you will find what you are looking for sadly.

Comment: Okay, it makes things a lot clearer, I still find that it seems 'uncomfortable' to work on our pipelines because we have to push and pull to test every changes but I get it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you use 'git commit --amend' and a development-branch working with a Jenkinsfile is pretty ok - not the best - but also not very annoying. Have fun with Jenkins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to JustAProgrammer and Holleoman, I understand that there is no way to do that properly.

Jenkins is build to interact with a SCM, doing all the things locally seems to make nonsense or is not the Jenkins way of thinking.

I'm closing this question for now !

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use File Scm plugin to select a local jenkins file.

Comment: After so many answers saying to copy in SSH keys and put all changes through the git remote for local testing, FINALLY a local-testing solution!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to have on job where I have a pipeline script, which I edit directly.
A second job which checks out my feature branch.
And a production job which checks out the master branch.

So I can experiment without messing up my git repo to much.